# Hyperlink in Stack Overflow Teams email is not mapped with any URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, email, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have received an email with the subject of "Welcome to Stack Overflow for Teams!". At the end of the email, there is a paragraph below:

> P.S. If you’re already familiar with Stack Overflow’s format, jump right in and ask your first question.

[image: Email]

The "ask your first question" looks like a hyperlink but it is not mapped with any URL, so clicking on that is not responding to any.

The hyperlink should be mapped with the "Ask Private Question" URL or the paragraph should be modified to avoid the hyperlink text.

**Inspecting the hyperlink element in the browser's developer tools shows there is no `href="..."` added.**

[image: No hyperlink]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My name is Stephanie and I am an analyst on the Stack Overflow for Teams Product Experience Team. I work on managing the build and delivery of end user communications to Teams users.

First things first, I appreciate you bringing this issue to our attention. The Product Experience Team manages a large volume of customer outreach emails and in-app posts that we use to inform and guide our users so they can experience the best that Stack Overflow for Teams has to offer.

In this particular instance, it seems like the error with this hyperlink was due to a syntax error – which is a fancy way of saying someone mistyped the hyperlink.

The link has been corrected, and all versions of this communication going forward should properly redirect users to their Teams site. We try our best to make sure we get everything right before sending out communication to users, but unfortunately we are still human and make mistakes sometimes.  We would like to apologize for any confusion this error may have caused.

In the future, please direct any Stack Overflow for Teams issues or bugs to the Product Support Team. They are an excellent resource and will be able to get these issues resolved in a more timely manner. You can learn more about [how to reach support here](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4972484-how-to-contact-support-for-stack-overflow-teams) or [submit a ticket here](https://stackenterprise.freshdesk.com/support/tickets/new?type=teams).